# Approach to spinning up 11 year old hard-drives?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, storage

I recently bought a IDE to USB converter to try to access some old data located on 3 IDE Sata harddrives that have not been used for 11 years. Not only have they not been used, they have been stored in cold storage room with high humidity.

I am wondering if there is any tips or precaution that need to be taken when dealing with old harddrives? 
Should i mount them a special way? 
And if i can get them running, what is the most safe way to transfer the data from the disk? (Windows or OSX)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the data in the drives is not of major importance. If it is you should consider professional recovery. Failed amateur attempts may complicate or prevent professional recovery.

Be sure to allow sufficient time for the drive to warm up to room temperature before power is applied. Depending on how cold it was this may require up to 24 hours. Most conventional drives are not sealed but exposed to filtered ambient air. Cold temperatures in themselves can be problematic and room temperature air will condense on a cold platter surface. You must allow time for this to evaporate. The platters will require considerably more time to warm up than the case. Do not disturb the drive during this time.

If the drive is formatted NTFS it would be best to do recovery from a non Windows OS. NTFS security may cause problems in Windows. These issues can be dealt with but they will take time and you may not have much of that. After 11 years the drive may not be functional and if it does work it may be only for a short time.

Others may have other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tips.
I took them in to dry and warm up for 2 days, and mounted them on a OSX partition. I managed to get 2 of the disks to fully restore. While the last one was not able to mount.